# Java applet security when using rxtx and build 1.7.0_25-b15

Tags: java, security, applet

Background:

I have a self-signed java applet which communicates successfully with A trial web server on my local net using build 1.7.0_21-b11 and FireFox (or Opera) Running on a windows XP (32 bit) virtual machine. The Applet is being used solely as a 'pass through' to transfer encrypted data to and from a special USB TTL232R-3v3 device. All the encryption and database manipulation is performed by PHP ,  and Javascript is being used to communicate with the server. Like this, I can minimise the number of page reloads..
This  works well enough apart from the (expected) complaint about a dodgy certificate.

The Problem:

Using a clone of the above virtual machine but with build 1.7.0_25-b17 installed, I now find that the Applet is being blocked. The reason given is Invalid Permissions value : all-permissions.

I have placed codebase :  *   and  permissions : all-permissions in the manifest file of the (netbeans) project file for the applet, which appear to be 'seen' by jarsigner.
anyone have any clues?

The older java VM still runs the applet with the modified manifest BTW.

Comment: Can you post the exact exception you are getting by the applet runtime?

Answer (score 6):

When we got that error-message with java 1.7.0_25 the reason was an additional blank after all-permissions in the manifest file.

So check whether there is any whitespace between "Permissions: all-permissions" and the following linebreak.

Comment: That was the problem indeed - advice most appreciated sir!

Comment: This absolutly saved my day!